# Installing a certificate as part of a WiX package

Tags: wix, wix3.6

As part of our client-server software package, we have a custom CA that issues certificates. I need to be able to install our CA as a trusted root CA on each user's machine. In order to accomplish this, I'm using the `Certificate` element from the IIS management package for WiX (the cert isn't for IIS, but this serves our purposes). Originally, I had the installer placing it in the local machine store, but we've had to make our installer a per-user install in order to avoid requiring elevation, so I must now store it in the local user store.

I've changed the store location to `currentUser`, which works, but now I'm prompted with a warning about installing the certificate every time the installer is run, and both a warning about removing and installing the certificate when a new version of the installer is run to upgrade. I got no such warnings when using the local machine store.

**Is there a way to do either of the following:**

- Have the installer only install the certificate if it doesn't already exist and *not* remove it upon uninstallation (so an upgrade wouldn't remove it in the first place, eliminating one warning, and then wouldn't install it since it was already there, eliminating the other warning)
- Have the installer perform the remove/install certificate actions without prompting the user

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't an exact solution to what I asked, I did find a solution that worked for me.

I set `Permanent="true"` on the `Component` for my certificate and gave it a condition like below:

```
<Component Id="MyCert" Permanent="True">
    <Certificate ... />
    <Condition><![CDATA[SKIPCERT <> "YES"]]></Condition>
</Component>
```

This works for me because I use a bootstrapper application for my updates, so I'm able to pass a custom variable named `SKIPCERT` a value of `YES` when I'm upgrading.

The `Permanent="True"` combined with the condition means that the certificate is not removed upon uninstallation (or upgrading) and when I'm installing an update it doesn't try to install it again.

Comment: I did a test on Windows 7 Ultimate x64bit and I didn't get those errors.  What OS(es) were you testing on?  Was the MSI package perUser or perMachine?  I used perUser in my test with store location to currentUser.

Comment: Also FYI to anybody else: Marking the component permanent means the user can never uninstall whatever the component contains.  Since your using the burn bootstrapper you could move the cert install to a separate MSI and mark that permanent in the bundle.  MSIs marked permanent in a bundle are automatically shown in Add and remove programs.  That way the user can easily uninstall it if they want.